# Is it possible to create a compositor node with PyNodes that outputs camera clip_start and clip_end?

Tags: customization, compositing-nodes, pynodes

Im not looking for a how to, but some of you may know if this is possible or not. An example of a dummy node added to compositor would be much appreciated, i can't find any (or i'm looking in all the wrong places)

The PyNodes documentation is [here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User%3aPhonybone/Python_Nodes), The TextEditor template Custom Node creates a custom node tree, but what am I supposed to do with that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PyNodes do not make it possible to extend Blender Internal, Cycles or the compositor with new nodes.

They are designed to make user interfaces for new node systems. For example developers of external render engines can use them to make their own shader node systems, or an addon could make a new geometry node system.

It would of course be very useful if they did, but that would be a much bigger project, as it requires each node system to expose an API with access to its inner workings.

Comment: Thanks @brecht, i'm watching the Geometry Nodes addon like a hawk.

Comment: I don't know if there is actually a geometry nodes addon in development, it's just an example of something this could be used for.

Comment: there is / was http://wiki.blender.org/uploads/b/b9/Blender2.67_pynodes_geometry_nodes_addon.png https://www.gitorious.org/blender-trunk/addons/trees/geometry_nodes/py/scripts/addons/geometry_nodes

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if this is possible with `PyNodes`, Seems like the sort of thing you'd use `Drivers` for.

You can use node settings to drive these values too,
Add a driver to the cameras clipping, and set the driver to point to a scene property, eg: `node_tree.nodes["Mix"].inputs[0].default_value`

[image: Example setup]

And the other way around you can do too, of course. Add a driver to a value node, and set the driver to point to the camera property like clip_sta and clip_end.

[image: Second example setup]

Comment: using drivers is indeed a solution, but I have to accept the definitive answer by brecht on whether or not PyNodes could do it